# Creating a Function for a Mosaic Plot with Ggmosaic using Standard Evaluation

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

library(ggmosaic)
library(tidyverse)

I'm still attempting to learn some of the nuances of programming with standard evaluation. For this problem, I'm attempting to create a function using the "happy" dataset from ggmosaic to create a basic mosaic plot of the variables "health" and "happy".

Below is the code that I want to use to create a function using standard evaluation. I want to be able to enter any two categorical variables from the happy dataset and create a basic mosaic plot as outlined in the code.

```
happy%>%
na.omit()%>%
count(happy,health)%>%
ggplot()+
geom_mosaic(aes(weight=n,x=product(health),fill=health))
```

However, I can't quite get the code right. I've asked similar questions before, but I'm still struggling to understand when and where to use the .dots argument as well as how to specify the inputs in standard evaluation. Below is one of the incorrect versions of code I've been playing with...

```
Mosaic<-function(product="health",fill="happy"){
happy%>%na.omit()%>%
count_(c(product,fill))%>%
ggplot()+
geom_mosaic(aes_string(weight="n",x=product(product),fill=fill))
}
```

Any pointers to get this to work wouldbe be greatly appreciated, especially any advice on how to code this properly with SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
Mosaic<-function(var_product="health",fill="happy"){
  happy%>%
    na.omit()%>%
    count_(c(var_product,fill))%>%
    ggplot(aes(weight=n))+
    geom_mosaic(aes_string(x=paste0("product(", var_product, ")"),fill=fill))
}
```

Example:

```
Mosaic("sex","degree")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works perferctly. Just a question, why is it necessary to use paste0 for the x=product() part of the code? I'm hoping to understand this better for when I write other code.

Comment: Because `aes_string()` is used, the expression must be a string. `paste0()` creates a string combining "product(" and the input variable.